# Any other option for bundling python apps, besides cxFreeze, pyinstaller and similars?

Tags: python, python-3.x, virtualenv, pyinstaller, cx-freeze

I've tried bundling my application with PyInstaller and CxFreeze but both gave me lots of issues. I think this *might* be caused by the fact that I'm using lots of libraries such as TF, Keras, Pandas, Pillow, OpenCV, etc..

Is there any other option for bundling my python app? I do not need to distribute it, I just need to bring it to school to show it to my professor without having to install python or any other library.

I thought of making a USB with a virtualenv on it, and install all the necessary libraries but then, when I try to run the script, it complains about lots of missing files from the standard library that virtualenv didn't copy. So I have to go to my Python installation folder and copy those to the venv, which seems kind of ugly.

Is there a better option?

EDIT: PortablePython is not an option because it's not Python3 compatible and because it's discontinued

Comment: If you are already using conda packages, I have found constructor to be quite useful.

Comment: @Simon yes, I’m very sure. Look closely at the top answer there; it’s none of the ones the OP has named here. Portable Python is designed specifically for this use case; to be able to run Python stand-alone from a USB stick.

Comment: @MartijnPieters  Ah I see, yes you were correct

Comment: @MartijnPieters It's not being developed anymore, it's a closed project.

Comment: Generally speaking: unless your professor runs Windows machines only, they will have access to Python. Otherwise, get yourself a PythonAnywhere account and run your code there, or run it on ideone or similar online environments.

Comment: We have Windows machines and can't use PythonAnywhere or IdeOne because my program needs to comunicate with another process via udp